# How can I find the key when I have to value using namevaluecollection?

Tags: c#, .net, search

I google'd around for this for a good twenty minutes. Forgive me if this is a duplicate.

So I am reading from a app.config file and have a bunch of keys/value pairs

```
{'a','1'},{'b','5'},{'c','9'} ... etc
```

Finding the values when give the keys are easy. But going reverse proves to be much more difficult than I thought it would.

Strangely the api on msdn does not seem to mention anything about reverse search.
How would you find the value of the key if you were only given "1" if you are allowed to at all?

Comment: If the values are all distinct (else your question doesn't make sense), why not copy them into a global hashtable with the values as keys and the keys as values?

Comment: Yes the values are all distinct, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nicest way I can think to do it is to use Linq on the `AllKeys` property:

```
myNameValueCollection.AllKeys.First(key => myNameValueCollection[key] == myValue);
```

It is unfortunate that `NameValueCollection` does not implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

I see from your comments that you're not very familiar with Linq.  I've provided some links in the comments to get you going.  This particular Linq query is approximately equivalent to the following, written very tersely:

```
foreach(var key in myNameValueCollection.AllKeys)
{
    var value = myNameValueCollection.AllKeys[key];
    if (value == myValue)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what [key => myNameValueCollection[key] == myValue] is doing? Or link me to an online resource that can better explain how it works?

Comment: This is using lambda expression syntax - a common practice in C#.  The Linq library makes especially nice use of it.  The `First` operator looks for the first `key` in `myNameValueCollection.AllKeys` for which the anonymous function parameter evaluates to `true`.  So here, we are looking for the first `key` such that if we look at the corresponding value in `myValueCollection`, it equals the desired value.  Read more about Linq here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx and lambda expressions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is a one way street because the hashing function is applied to the key and not the value. However there are obvious work arounds if you're values are distinct (keep in mind they don't have to be). Eugen's suggestion in the comments is probably the best if you're going to repeatedly do look ups by the values. If you're looking for more of a one off solution you can just loop over the keys checking for a match on the value. When the value matches you know what key it's associated with.